# How can I change the font size in Smartface editor?

Tags: smartface.io

I don't see any settings panel/section for the IDE.
How can I change the font size in the code editor?

P.S. I'm using a HiDpi display so the default size is very small

Answer (score 0):

For existing release , there is no option for changing the font sizes.

Smartface App Studio 4.4 will be released soon, than you can change it by editing the theme files which are ;

C:\Program Files (x86)\Smartface\Smartface App Studio 4.4\Data\ScriptEditorTheme.ini

C:\Program Files (x86)\Smartface\Smartface App Studio 4.4\Data\ScriptEditorThemeDark.ini

C:\Program Files (x86)\Smartface\Smartface App Studio 4.4\Data\ScriptEditorThemeYellow.ini

Comment: Any news on when Smartface App Studio 4.4 will be released?